# Mapping Customers DB to my to my databse

Tags: java, data, mongodb, mapping

I'm trying to connect to various customers and map their databases to my database. I need a tool that I can comfortably map their database column/keys to my keys. currently, I'm writing big mapping files in MongoDB that try to map their DB to my DB (including types conversion, and what fields to ignore, and what to map to what... ) but I find it rather complicated... I'm also building a java application running on top of that which is also uncomfortable to read from such a dynamic MongoDB file. Other ideas and tools will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain "mapping"? Do you means combining? Or finding common, overlapping data? or something else?

Comment: e.g. i have a schema with {"id","name","happinessLevel(Integer)} and customer a has {"eid","firstname","lastname","Happiness(string)} and customer2 has {"myId","name","happy(boolean)} i need a to create a configuravble manipulations to map various schemas to my schema)